# How to get user's Gmail address from smack?

Tags: xmpp, smack, google-talk

I'm struggling with Google talk and smack. I got as far as enabling unsafe applications and authenticating with an email address and password, but can't get the Google ids of the contacts. Apparently Google talk uses generated JIDs to hide user's identities and enable anonymous public chat conversations. But that ID (...@public.talk.google.com) while seemingly persistent doesn't mean much to a human user.

How can I translate that to an old fashioned google id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can continue using "safe" applications if your xmpp library will implement Google X-OAUTH2 authentication mechanism, Smack library provides `SASLXOauth2Mechanism` class for it.
2. `VCardManager` Smack helper is able to `loadVCard(jid)` for each contact you have, and give you details about contact

Comment: Thank you. Seams that Google is very privacy-aware, my vcard doesn't contain my email address, even though I have added the other user on Google plus, exchanged emails, went to hangouts: did every friendly thing Google offers.